# Libreria JS is not defined

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con las librerias, tengo una landing page que tiene sus js y css y tengo otro template para los usuarios que tienen sus propios css y js a excepción de uno que comparten entre los dos y el problema esta que en landing tiene el login y no uso datatables entonces me tira error de **datatables is not defined** o **vue is not defined** y no termina de cargar la página si no importo el js, cosa que si uso en el template de usuarios.
Hay alguna forma de solucionar esto? intenté hacer lo siguiente que vé en internet pero no anduvo:

```
if (typeof DataTable !== 'undefined') {
   $(".datatables").DataTable();      
}
```

Comment: por lo general cuando ocurre el error que no esta definido es porque estas inicializando los plugins antes de cargar el js del propio plugin o directamente no lo estas agregando en el sitio. podras poner el codigo donde inicializas y el codigo donde vinculas el js en la landing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que DataTable es un plugin adscrito a JQuery por tanto solo debes hacerlo de esta manera:

Conociendo de antemano que DataTable es un método de JQuery:

```js
if (typeof $().DataTable == 'function') {
  alert("soy una funcion de JQuery");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Simplemente para saber si no existe como variable o función dentro de JQuery:

```js
if (typeof $().DataTable == 'undefined') {
  alert("simplemente no existo");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Adapta lo anterior a tu problema puntualmente, espero que te sea de utilidad.